# Error connecting to Microsoft SQL Server from SAS Enterprise Guide

Tags: sql-server, sas

I am trying to connect to SQL Server from SAS Enterprise Guide with `ODBC.ini` configuration file using `libname` statement:

```
libname test sqlsvr dsn = 'SQL server' user='domain\user' password='password' schema='XXX'
```

but I get this error:

> Login failed.The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with integrated authentication.

After searching the net, I found https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/login-untrusted-domain-when-connecting-sql-server-odbc-connector but it didn't help.

I need to do the task for my job because other users need to connect themselves to DB using this ODBC.ini file.

I'm completely new to the field and I really appreciate any help, including suggesting useful resources.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to SQL Server from a different, untrusted domain? You **can't** do that. You can use Windows authentication *only* if both machines are in the same domain or if one domain trusts the other. That's what the error says. You'll have to use SQL Server accounts instead. When Windows Authentication is used the client application (in this case SAS) connects to the server using the current user's login. It doesn't send the credentials to that server. The server can only trust account from the same domain.

Comment: Why aren't both servers on the same domain anyway? This is a *very* unusual setup. If the company uses Windows domains (as it should), why aren't both machines on the same domain?  If putting them on different domains was a conscious decision, why don't the domains trust each other? Is there a Windows domain at all? Or is the company using standalone computers in a Workgroup setup?

Comment: If one or both of the servers were left out of the domain by mistake, your Windows administrator can add them. That's the easiest solution. Otherwise you'll have to create a new SQL Server login, give it the necessary permissions and configure SAS to use that login

Comment: Are you setting up a new server? Did you forget to join it to the AD domain before installing SAS?

Comment: first of all, thank you for your explanations and questions. well, since I am not familiar with the topic that much I do not have all the answers but I'll try my best: the connection works if I use SQL server accounts but the client users need to connect themselves with a username that has domain; so, when I put their usernames I get the error. I do not know why the machines are on different servers tho. but how can I give the authentication for a specific domain in SAS? in other words, can I make a specific domain trusted from SAS?

Comment: the thing that I do not understand is that if this authentication and permission to domain can happen from SAS side or it should be done by Windows administrator? because, I am the SAS reference at the moment and if it is something that should be solved by me I have to find the solution, but if I know that the it's the duty of Windows administrator then I would know there is nothing I can do on my side. that is the main question. sorry if I am repeating myself and if you could give me some references to inform myself in the right direction I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: In general, the article you pointed out should have solved the issue. Can you please paste redacted DSN definition from ODBC.ini. In general, if you are using NTLM protocol for authentication to SQL Server, the host where SAS is running does not need to be member of any domain. In fact, if you wish to use 'trusted connections' feature to authenticate to SQL Server, you will be effectively using the Kerberos protocol - in the example shown above you most likely are trying to authenticate using NTLM so quick peek into ODBC.ini should explain a lot to us.